# how do I pull Score from this MASSIVE json object?

Tags: php, function

I want $result['score'] but It never returns true despite trying  $result->score, $result[0] and $result[stdClass]['score'];  All help is greatly appreciated.

```
Object(stdClass)#1 (9) { ["kind"]=> string(22) "pagespeedonline#result" ["id"]=> string(34) "https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl" ["responseCode"]=> int(200) ["title"]=> string(6) "Google" ["score"]=> int(92) ["pageStats"]=> object(stdClass)#2 (9) { ["numberResources"]=> int(13) ["numberHosts"]=> int(5) ["totalRequestBytes"]=> string(4) "2295" ["numberStaticResources"]=> int(8) ["htmlResponseBytes"]=> string(6) "190230" ["imageResponseBytes"]=> string(5) "45452" ["javascriptResponseBytes"]=> string(6) "780563" ["otherResponseBytes"]=> string(4) "1867" ["numberJsResources"]=> int(4) } ["formattedResults"]=> object(stdClass)#3 (2) { ["locale"]=> string(5) "en_US" ["ruleResults"]=> object(stdClass)#4 (10) { ["AvoidLandingPageRedirects"]=> object(stdClass)#5 (3) { ["localizedRuleName"]=> string(28) "Avoid landing page redirects" ["ruleImpact"]=> float(7) ["urlBlocks"]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#6 (1) { ["header"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["format"]=> string(96) "Your page has $1 redirects. Redirects introduce additional delays before the page can be loaded." ["args"]=> array(1) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#8 (2) { ["type"]=> string(11) "INT_LITERAL" ["value"]=> string(1) "2" } } } }
```

[Here is a copy](http://pastebin.com/UNKgVCJc) of a formatted pastebin of the object

Will do:

```
"{\n \"kind\": \"pagespeedonline#result\",\n \"id\": \"https:\/\/www.google.com\/?gws_rd=ssl\",\n \"responseCode\": 200,\n \"title\": \"Google\",\n \"score\": 92,\n \"pageStats\": {\n \"numberResources\": 12,\n \"numberHosts\": 5,\n \"totalRequestBytes\": \"2186\",\n \"numberStaticResources\": 8,\n \"htmlResponseBytes\": \"189695\",\n \"imageResponseBytes\": \"45452\",\n \"javascriptResponseBytes\": \"780569\",\n \"otherResponseBytes\": \"1595\",\n \"numberJsResources\": 4\n },\n \"formattedResults\": {\n \"locale\": \"en_US\",\n \"ruleResults\": {\n \"AvoidLandingPageRedirects\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Avoid landing page redirects\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 7.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"Your page has $1 redirects. Redirects introduce additional delays before the page can be loaded.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"INT_LITERAL\",\n \"value\": \"2\"\n }\n ]\n }\n },\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"Avoid landing page redirects for the following chain of redirected URLs.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/AvoidRedirects\"\n }\n ]\n },\n \"urls\": [\n {\n \"result\": {\n \"format\": \"$1\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"URL\",\n \"value\": \"http:\/\/google.com\/\"\n }\n ]\n }\n },\n {\n \"result\": {\n \"format\": \"$1\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"URL\",\n \"value\": \"http:\/\/www.google.com\/\"\n }\n ]\n }\n },\n {\n \"result\": {\n \"format\": \"$1\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"URL\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/www.google.com\/?gws_rd=ssl\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n }\n ]\n },\n \"EnableGzipCompression\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Enable compression\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"You have compression enabled. Learn more about enabling compression.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/EnableCompression\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"LeverageBrowserCaching\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Leverage browser caching\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"You have enabled browser caching. Learn more about browser caching recommendations.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/LeverageBrowserCaching\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"MainResourceServerResponseTime\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Reduce server response time\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.09,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"In our test, your server responded in $1. There are many factors that can slow down your server response time. Please read our recommendations to learn how you can monitor and measure where your server is spending the most time.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"DURATION\",\n \"value\": \"0.21 seconds\"\n },\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/Server\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"MinifyCss\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Minify CSS\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"Your CSS is minified. Learn more about minifying CSS.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/MinifyResources\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"MinifyHTML\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Minify HTML\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"Your HTML is minified. Learn more about minifying HTML.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/MinifyResources\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"MinifyJavaScript\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Minify JavaScript\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"Your JavaScript content is minified. Learn more about minifying JavaScript.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/MinifyResources\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"MinimizeRenderBlockingResources\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Eliminate render-blocking JavaScript and CSS in above-the-fold content\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"You have no render-blocking resources. Learn more about removing render-blocking resources.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/BlockingJS\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"OptimizeImages\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Optimize images\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"Your images are optimized. Learn more about optimizing images.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/OptimizeImages\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n },\n \"PrioritizeVisibleContent\": {\n \"localizedRuleName\": \"Prioritize visible content\",\n \"ruleImpact\": 0.0,\n \"urlBlocks\": [\n {\n \"header\": {\n \"format\": \"You have the above-the-fold content properly prioritized. Learn more about prioritizing visible content.\",\n \"args\": [\n {\n \"type\": \"HYPERLINK\",\n \"value\": \"https:\/\/developers.google.com\/speed\/docs\/insights\/PrioritizeVisibleContent\"\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n ]\n }\n }\n },\n \"version\": {\n \"major\": 1,\n \"minor\": 15\n },\n \"screenshot\": {\n \"data\": \"_9j_4AAQSkZJRgABAQAAAQABAAD_2wBDAAYEBQYFBAYGBQYHBwYIChAKCgkJChQODwwQFxQYGBcUFhYaHSUfGhsjHBYWICwgIyYnKSopGR8tMC0oMCUoKSj_2wBDAQcHBwoIChMKChMoGhYaKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCgoKCj_wAARCADwAUADASIAAhEBAxEB_8QAHAABAAIDAQEBAAAAAAAAAAAAAAMIAgUGBAEH_8QAQxAAAQMCAgQKCQEGBgMBAAAAAAECAwQRBSEGEhMUFzFBUVJVYZLR0iJTVHGBkZOhogcVMjNCVmIjNHOx4fAllMHx_8QAGgEBAAIDAQAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAECAwQFBv_EADERAQABAwIEAwUIAwAAAAAAAAABAgMREiEEMVFhBSJBE1KRoeEGFBVicYHB8DJC0f_aAAwDAQACEQMRAD8A0mj1JhNU6oTGa6SjRqNWJWNvrqt7ouS8WSkkeG4Q-VzFxpsaN1V2joXKjkc29kTk1VRUW_OluUsfwZ6H9RU_ff5hwZ6H9RU_ff5gK30eHYTLQ08tTjCQzuussSRKqtzRERO211uZswrCNaRrsejy_dckDrLxcl7-4sbwZ6H9RU_ff5hwZ6H9RU_ff5gK5swjDJFercajZDHHCrpHRKus96rrI1OP0bJcjbhuFK9rHY0xLtR202Llal0ddtuO6K1M_wC9OZSyHBlof1FTd9_mHBnof1FT99_mArhQ4XhUtHHLVY3FDK5l3Q7Fyqxea_Ln80PsuDYeyWl_81AsE6SqsqxL6GrbVul7-lf7LxljuDPQ_qKn77_MODLQ_qKm77_MBW6PDsL3iobJjDNky2zckLkWS7VW_LazrIvOfcQw3CYXXpcZSZqva2yQrdEuiK5V5kzX7FkODPQ_qKn77_MODPQ_qKn77_MBXSPCcHWVqP0gi1eVUp3ImSrdPsllt_MmRBPhuGMSNYsZjerpWNcmxcmo1eN3bqlkuDPQ_qKn77_MODPQ_qKn77_MBXGKhwXe0jfiL1hTZo6X93jR2u5qKi3sqNRG9qrcR4VhKus_H4mpeyqlO5eRFumfOqp8Cx3Bnof1FT99_mHBnof1FT99_mArDidLT0zo90ro6xrm3crWK1WrnlZfhn2mgoXR1mK19NWY9HhSR22Cyxo5rlst0VeS1k-Zb3gz0P6ip--_zGC_pdoW5VV2j1GqryqrvECpuwoN3a9NOKLaKjfQ3R_Hnfk4rW7bryIeOF8Ej6LW0rp4mTM1pVfTOVYFRiO1VREzu5ValuYt9wW6Ff09R_l4nzgt0K_p2j_LxAqRURQxOp1ZpjQvjm2npJA7_D1WqqI5ETl9FMuVV5jF7KdrJnJplQu2bVc1Epn3kVL2REtxrb7lueC3Qr-naL8vE-8FuhX9O0f5eIFQMOqZHYvWUyV7K6niT0J2M1WvzT0kTjT4m4sWob-l-hjVu3R-kaq8yvT_AOmXBlof1FT99_mAqrYWLVcGWh_UVP33-YcGWh_UVP33-YCqthYtVwZaH9RU_ff5hwZaH9RU_ff5gKq2Fi1XBlof1FT99_mHBlof1FT99_mAqrYWLVcGWh_UVP33-YcGWh_UVP33-YCqthYtVwZ6H9RU3ff5hwZ6H9RU3ff5gKq2Fi1XBnof1FT99_mHBlof1FT99_mAqrYWLVcGeh_UVP33-YcGeh_UVP33-YCqthYshNo5-mUM0kUsOFMkjcrXNWoddFTJUX0jD9g_pd6vCP8A2HeYzRw16f8ASfhLH7a370fFXKx6auGmjgpnU9Qssr23lYrbbN3Nfl9_w5LliKfRr9M6meOGCDCpJZHI1jG1DlVyrxInpG54M9D-oqfvv8xSu3XRtXGFqa6av8Zy7EAFFgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABqJ4MW3yV1PUQNhVUVqSJrZcyJbL5qT4YzEUkldiMkCtX9xsV7JmvHdOaxsABp5Y8ba-RYZqN7VfdjXtW6N1uVU41tkfcO_bLpIX126tiW-uxqLrpll2XubcAaTSqmramjhbh7ZXSI9yu2cmottm5E_nbyqnL4p68Dinhw1jKtHpMj5FXXdrLZXqqZ6zuS3L8uI2AArbiEtNHpNi-_RPkjWedERvG12utl_wD0xqn4KjI3U7at0jnNc5qqmq1Nb0m90sksbFW6saq-4-bKPoN-SHoI8d5eSdvzfRy_w3n5vl9VdcBdSu0ywbcGzNh3qG6SqirfXz4uTiLGmKRsRboxqL7jI5_H8d98qpnGMR1y2uF4b2ETGc5AAc9tAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAABVREuuSHlxSthw3D6isqXasMEayOXsRD82wnCcT0_1sTxutnpMJc5Up6SB1roi2vzfFbqufEhtWOGi5TNyurTTHr36RHqwXb2iYopjMy_UWPa9Lscjk50W5kfn7f07TDayCp0dxisoXtem0R6o9HNvnll8luh36ZJx3KX7dujE2q9UT2xMf39VrdddWddOPm-ghjqoJJXRRzROlbxsa9FVPgTXMGWaYmOYDBkrHqqMe1ypx2W9jJ7msarnKjWpmqqtkQiJireETtzfQQtqYZI0fHNG5irZHI9FRV5rnFaGTzSac6WxyTSPjjlZqMc9VRvHxJyEVTpmIn1Yq7sU1U0-9_zLuwQ71Bt9jtott6vXTW-XGTFmaYmOYAAgAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAHN_qLTy1WheKxwIqv2SPsnKjXI5U-SKYfpvWQVehuGbu5v-DGkL2p_K5vHf8A3-J0zkRUsuaHAVmhWJYViM1dobiLaNJVvJSSpeNV7Mly7FTLnN-xXbu2J4eurTOcxM8uWMS1btNVFyLtMZ2xLPF8H0qikratulEdPRtV8qNWH-GzNbXtyIcdU6R45WaF4fTy1sqVGK4g6nSpX0VSJEalkVLfzL9lOom0Z0s0g1YNI8Xp4cPuivipUzf9kT539xvNJNDKLFdGoMKpl3TdbOpZGpfZuTn578vzJ8RrieFmzE01Vz7sRGIjviN5bPhM02-NovXYmKI677-k46RzcxpB-nGGYVo7UV2FTVUGJUUSztqdqt3q1LrfmvbkPfg-MVekeCYDFPIsb6ti7d7ctdWuVt_jq396nkqtHNOMXpEwrFsWoGYetmyzRNVZJWpz5Jf7dp1kmjMEGFUNLhj1p5KFqNheud-e_vXO55Pj-GuXbNUWKZiNsxy1RmMx-8Zju9He4mmLdNN-7FdeZmJjfEY6464nHph5MZweHCqPfsNfJDNCqL-_fWS9jnMdfLpdplQ4HUTSQYaylbVTRxrZZFVqLb7onZmdVLheLYkrIsUqYW0zVu5sSZvNTphgjJcdw6qwTE6agx-NmpDFI7-MxEXK3uunFZTe-zduLXF3Ltu3NqiacRExyq382IzjbbP7uB4nVNdmmmqrVMTv-nTPq5nTvRKi0fkwmowt0sdPLWRsfA6RXJrXujkvy2RUIcSxaowWt0-qqJysqVmhiY9ONiucqX99r27T7pnSaQOrcEfpDWU0k8lW1kFLTJkiXS717eJDrmaEuqa7ShcSljdR4srVjSNV141aqqirdLXRbKd3xiLldizmvVV5t_r_AC5nARRTx1FyqjyU1RMx2xPp_D83psIw_E8Pjh0dw_FcTxxdV8uJbRYoopONc147cXPy3P23RqPEYcEpI8afHJiDGasr41ujlTiW9uO1r9pwtNo7p1QUCYPQ4th6Ye1FYyo1VbKxnMmWS_8Abn6Bg1JNQ4ZTU1TVy1k0TEa-eW2s9edTh8LbmmczEx8o_vd6_wAY4mL1EUxXFUZzG8zV8cRER-WIe0AG64AAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAilnbG9rVR7nKirZrVXIx3lPVTfTUnTKMwnBBvKeqm-mo3lPVTfTUnTJmE4IN5T1U301G8p6qb6ajTJmE4IN5T1U301G8p6qb6ajTJmE4IN5T1U301G8p6qb6ajTJmE5oNKdFqDSJkS1KyQ1UP8ACqIVs9vZ2objeU9VN9NRvKeqm-mpe3VctVRXRtMK1xRXGmreHL4FoNR4bibMRrKyrxKtj_hvqXXRnaic515BvKeqm-mo3lPVTfTUteuXb1Wq5OZRbootxijZOCDeU9VN9NRvKeqm-mpi0yvmE4IN5T1U301G8p6qb6ajTJmE4IN5T1U301Mop2yPc1Ee1yJezmqmRGmTMJQAQkAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAB53f55n-m7_AHQ9GRFLBtJGvSR7HIipdts0X3p2GOwf7TN-PgW2nG6vJPkMiDYP9pm_HwGwf7TN-PgMR1TnsnyGRBsH-0zfj4DYP9pm_HwGI6meyfIZEGwf7TN-PgNg_wBpm_HwGI6meyfIZEGwf7TN-PgNg_2mb8fAYjqZ7J8hkQbB_tM34-A2D_aZvx8BiOpnsnyGRBsH-0zfj4DYP9pm_HwGI6meyfIZEGwf7TN-PgNg_wBpm_HwGI6meyfIZEGwf7TN-PgNg_2mb8fAYjqZ7J8jzt_zzv8ATT_dT7sH-0zfj4H2KDUkc9ZHvcqInpWyT4INozuc0wAKpAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAEcsmpbK9zDeEva2fvMau66tkXlNLNhCPqJJW1NXFtH66tjdZL2VOa_L9gN5vH9q_MJUIvEn3OcjwFyVKyvr611lbqemt0RLXRV7dVLksuCo-Wd8dVWQ7Vz3K2J1kRXJZVtb4_EDfbx_avzMmzayOWy5JfjOfZgqNnglWqrHuhdrJrPvdc737FvZUNzCi6kuS8XMBLvCc33G8Je1s-a5qsQw9lbqK90rHMa5GuZkqX1c0XkX0fup51wZqxtbvFYj2x7JJEf6dtfW4_t7gN7vCXtq5-8bwnRX5nOuwBqzbXfK_adLaZ21lW17cWZlHg0iU6MkrapZdR7Flb-9ZX66ZrzWRPcB0G8f2r8zOKXXVUta3ac1-w3NrIqiOtrEVHNV6OddHtaqrqr772vzHQUl9Z10Xi5gPSAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAAA8m8v6LRvL-i0hNdU4fLNM-SOtmiVzmus1EsmrxW_7mBt95fzNG8u5mmmXDahc_2lU69rI5eTO_ESU1JUQ1LXOq5JYUa67H862tbsQDa7y_otG8v6LTy1Ee1gkj1lbrtVt05Lpa5rmYZOxjGMxCZrG8TUb_zz8QG73l3M0by_otNO7D6leLE6hOa6J2eC_NTZATby_otG8v5mmpmw-R9U6eOsmjV38qIlkyslv-_Imo6aWB8jpamSfWRETWS2qiX8QNhvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_otIQBNvL-i0by_op9yE8tZSJUvjcsj2LHdWqxbZrbP4WA2G8u5mjeX9Fpp20FSx10xCZzURURjky7M0_wC-890DXMhjbI9Xva1Ec5f5ltmoHq3l_RT7jeXczTXVdGs0qSxzPhkRurrMRL2vexhBRTRTRvWunka1VVWPzR2Sp_z8ANpvL-i0by_op9yE1SYVKiNaldM1iLdGtyS9_fdfiBu95dzNG8v6LTTxUNUyojctfK6JllVq8blvmi9hsgP_2Q==\",\n \"height\": 240,\n \"mime_type\": \"image\/jpeg\",\n \"width\": 320\n }\n}\n"
```

As per request this is the output I get from changing my echo to `echo "Score Speed is: ". print_r(json_decode($result[0]->score, true)) . "<br/>";`

(and also with `echo "Score Speed is: ". print_r(json_decode($result[0]->score)) . "<br/>";`)

Score Speed is: 1

sorry it's not more descriptive.

Final Edit: thank you for your help everyone... this combination yielded my data:

```
    $formatted = json_decode($results, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT);
```

//I had the old version using `True` instead of `JSON_PRETTY_PRINT`

```
    echo "formatted data: " . $formatted[0]->score . "<br/>";
```

//This ended up not working

```
    echo "2nd try: ". $formatted['score'];
```

//This one DOES work.

...

...

```
      //This is the [original piece of code I used as a reference point is here][2]
    echo '<pre>';  
    print_r(json_decode($results['score'],true));   
    echo '</pre>';
```

Comment: Could you supply the raw json dump?

Comment: I thought so too Scuzzy but alas that does not resolve either: http://puu.sh/oVNFS/d21d63efa6.png

Comment: That isn't json. That's a `var_dump()` of the data - In your screen shot I can see a `var_dump(json_decode())`. I just need the JSON

Comment: Darren would that not matter in this case though? if I removed var_dump the aim is still the same...it's there so I can determine the response outputs.  @adrin27 thank you I didn't know that I could do that - thought it was one or the other

Comment: Did it solve your problem? If not try to give us the `print_r()`

Comment: @aldrin27 no dice...right now I'm trying: `echo "Score Speed is: ". print_r(json_decode($result[0]->score, true)) . "<br/>";` that returns 1 (for true?) and not the actual value itself

Comment: @Frankenmint help us help you please ... dump the raw json. Purpose is for us to try to make sense of the stream and suggest best approach for extracting your Score. json_encode($result,JSON_PRETTY_PRINT), echo/log/print it somewhere and paste it here.

Comment: No it should return `92` only. Can you `print_r()` the data that supplied all of that object?

Answer (score 2):

You're going about this the wrong way. You're trying to decode an already decoded value.

Simply try `echo`'ing out the value:

```
echo $result[0]->score;
```

---

That's the end step. I feel that every step before this is incorrect - leading you to this issue of you not being able to print out the expected value.

You should be running through a process like the following:

```
$data = FETCH_THE_JSON_FROM_DATA_SOURCE();
$json = json_decode($data);
// now we find data
echo $json[0]->score;
```

<sup>*Note: Above code is pseudo code, you'll need to fill in your parts appropriately.*</sup>

We can't tell you how to get it if we can't see the raw `json` data. So help us help you.

Comment: 2nd edit: found a typo that was likely a culprit.  hold on pls